# Setting up tomcat 8.5 on RHEL 7

Tags: openssl, tomcat8

I'm trying to install Tomcat 8.5 on RedHat Enterprise 7.2. I'm having issue compiling Tomcat Native 1.2. RedHat 7 ships OpenSSL 1.01 and Tomcat Native 1.2 needs OpenSSL 1.0.2 so I had to compile OpenSSL 1.0.2.

So When I ran the following command:
`"./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/usr/java/default"`, I get the following error when I try to run "make":

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.10-src/native'
/bin/sh /usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link  gcc -pthread  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE   -g -O2 -DHAVE_OPENSSL -DHAVE_POLLSET_WAKEUP   -I/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.10-src/native/include -I/usr/java/default/include -I/usr/java/default/include/linux -I/usr/local/ssl/include  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -version-info 2:10:2   -Wl,-z,relro  -o libtcnative-1.la -rpath /usr/local/apr/lib src/address.lo src/bb.lo src/dir.lo src/error.lo src/file.lo src/info.lo src/jnilib.lo src/lock.lo src/misc.lo src/mmap.lo src/multicast.lo src/network.lo src/os.lo src/poll.lo src/pool.lo src/proc.lo src/shm.lo src/ssl.lo src/sslcontext.lo src/sslinfo.lo src/sslnetwork.lo src/sslutils.lo src/stdlib.lo src/thread.lo src/user.lo os/unix/system.lo os/unix/uxpipe.lo -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto  /usr/lib64/libapr-1.la  -lpthread -ldl
/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(ecp_nistz256.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libtcnative-1.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/tomcat-native-1.2.10-src/native'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I tried recompiling OpenSSL 1.0.2 with -fPIC (./config -fPIC) I'm still getting the same error.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks!